# Google API Exception "invalid_grant" in DEVs GlassFish but not in Local

Tags: java, oauth, google-api, glassfish

I'm working using OAuth 2.0 to authenticate to a Google's API and everything works just fine in my local GlassFish.
The problem begins when I'm deploying to the DEV's GlassFish, which throws me the following exception:

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant" }

This is my code:

```
        transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(transport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountUser(googleAdminEmail)
                .setServiceAccountId(googleAdminAccount)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(
                                DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER,
                                DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP,
                                DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(googleAdminKeyPath))
                .build();           

        credential.refreshToken();
```

The exact line that throws me the exception is:

```
 credential.refreshToken();
```

If I get the Access Token from my local run, let's say the token value is "usghiudblk", and I set that value when running on DEV's GlasshFish: `credential.setAcessToken("usghiudblk");` it will let me access normally but still this won't work:  `credential.refreshToken();`

I truly can't tell why everything works just fine in local but doesn't works in DEV's GlassFish.

Comment: how many times has the user granted you a refreshtoken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by the answer on this post:

[Invalid grant when accessing Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001668/invalid-grant-when-accessing-google-api)

The problem was that the server's clock was not synchronized with NTP.

That was it...